# SELECT conditionally based on values of two parameters

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling to write a conditional query based on the value of 3 params as follows, considering this table structure:

| id | product_type | category | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pants | shorts | blue |
| 2 | pants | dress pants | blue |
| 3 | pants | null | blue |
| 4 | pants | joggers | blue |
| 5 | pants | shorts | red |
| 6 | pants | null | null |

if my params are product_type, category, and color, I want to match:

- all three if all three have non null values
- product_type + category if all three have non null value but no match for all three
- product_type if all three have non null values but no match for product_type + category
- product_type + category if color is null
- product_type + color if category is null
- product_type if conditions above are not met

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: ```ORDER BY product_type = @product_type DESC NULLS LAST, ...```